# How many built-in Terminal Services Licenses does Windows Server 2008 have?

Tags: windows-server-2008

It was 5 for Windows Server 2003 right? Is it the same for windows server 2008? If not then how many are there now.

Answer (score 4):

There are two types of Terminal Services, the basic Terminal Services for Administration and the Terminal Services role (which would allow you to host applications or desktops).  By default, with Server 2003 and 2008, you can have two simultaneous connections to the Terminal Services for Administration connections (which require no additional licensing beyond a CAL per user).  If you want to use the full Terminal Server role, you will need to purchase additional licensing (TS CALs).  See the [Terminal Services Licening](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770371.aspx) on Technet  for more info.

Answer (score 4):

For Terminal Services access you need a Terminal Services CAL (TS CAL) for each user - in addition to the standard Windows Server CAL.

Windows Server does not come with any TS CALs (the 'sort of' exception is that in Remote Admin mode up to 2 admin sessions can access the server using remote sessions).  the fact that Windows Server typically comes with 5 CALs doesn't mean that it also comes with 5 TS CALs (licensing for Windows Server can be somewhat complex).

See the "What is the difference between a Windows Server CAL and a Terminal Services (TS) CAL?" question in the Client Access Licenses FAQ (http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/licensing-faq.aspx#cals).

Answer (score 1):

You failed to mention which edition you're asking about, but the CAL requirements for 2008 are the same as for 2003 R2 - so yes, that would be typically 5 CALs included. That depends, however, on which package you bought - many retailers offer packages with 5 CALs included, but there are also SKUs without any CALs included. However, these are not Terminal Services CALs.

There is no way to accurately answer your question without you providing more information about your deployment scenarios. Microsoft server licensing often tends to be... let's say, obscure.

You'll probably find most relevant information here:

[Windows Server 2008 Licensing FAQ](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/licensing-faq.aspx) -> [Client Access Licenses (CALs)](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/licensing-faq.aspx#cals)

Edit in light of other comments: Seems that I was wrong and there are no Terminal Services CALs included in the typical server SKUs beside the two administrator connections. Sorry. Upvoted the other answers.

Comment: it is the Server 2008 standard edition i referring to. Thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 0):

I have been playing with Server 2008 std.  By activating the TS License server role and pointing your TS Server role to 127.0.0.1 for a license server, you can log in with as many as 5 concurrent connections.